# Android Studio generating stub for a class not included in the Android Wear Support Library

Tags: java, android, google-play-services, android-support-library, wear-os

I'm not sure if I'm going crazy or what, but Android Studio 0.8.0 generates a Mobile + Wear app, but subclasses WatchActivity for the MainActivity of the watch itself. That would be all fine and dandy, but the class does not exist.

What are developers supposed to do? The only ones available, according to the JavaDocs, are android.support.wearable.activity.InsetActivity and android.support.wearable.activity.ConfirmationActivity.

Comment: Google sample code, as well as code snippets from the developers site are often broken and non-functional

Answer (score 7):

Auto-generated activity template has been changed in Android Studio 0.8.1. Now WatchActivity has been removed and activity class just extends Activity. Try update Android Studio and recreate the app again.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like there are a few errors with the generated class (TAG not defined, etc...). It was probably just rushed out. I changed it to extend `Activity` and everything compiles fine (I'm not at the point where it runs yet, so I'll update when that happens).

**EDIT:** I was able to run the app on the wearable emulator fine just by extending `Activity`.

Comment: Great now my hello world app runs...!